# Creating new columns when the paragraph reaches the bottom of the Div

Tags: jquery, css, html

So, I have a div with a fixed height, and a width that takes up the entire width of the screen. My goal is to make the div scroll sideways when too much content is added.

The paragraphs also have a much skinnier fixed width within the Div itself.

What I'd like to do is make any paragraph or content start a new "column" when it reaches the bottom of the Div. Is there a way to do this with jQuery or something of the sort?

```
.divClass {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    clear: both;
    background-size: 50%;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding-left: 80px;
}

.divClass p {
    width: 360px;
}
```

Comment: I think the [`column-fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-fill) CSS property (plus `overflow-x`) does what you want, but it is unfortunately only supported via vendor prefix in Firefox. This might require server-side or JavaScript processing.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/LB7VA/ for my best quick attempt.  Should not use `$.each` and instead iterate with a while loop so you can slice the word back into the array when the height goes over.  Also, not sure I have height working as intended.

Comment: is this what your asking http://jsfiddle.net/xPdD7/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (){

function  makeColumns(elementSelector,numOfColumns){
var caracCount =  $(elementSelector).html().replace(/ /g,'').length;

var caracCountColmuns = Math.ceil( (caracCount/numOfColumns).toFixed(1) ) ;

    $(elementSelector).css({
         '-moz-column-count':caracCountColmuns, /* Firefox */
        '-webkit-column-count':caracCountColmuns, /* Safari and Chrome */
        'column-count':caracCountColmuns,
    });

}

makeColumns(".divClass p",300);  // Call this anywhere makeColumns("elementToManipulate",HEIGHT OF EACH BLOCK)
});
```

I have Done your Solution here, 
[MakeColumns()](http://jsfiddle.net/Wandile/3rYX9/1/) This only works with IE10+, Chrome , Firefox, Safari and Opera. You can then Manipulate this to what ever you want.